# enabling vt-x on win8.1 without using BIOS

Tags: windows

I need to run VM on my acer laptop, with win8.1 that supports VT-x but it's disabled.
I contacted acer support and they said your BIOS doesn't allow you to change it, or something like that.

it was enabled and I was able to run VM, then it suddenly diabled.

I want to enable it using cmd, or any other way rather than using bios, because this junk acer laptop doesn't allow me to change it from the bios.

thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer and it worked for me, by disabling the hyper-V.
here is the command:

```
    bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

and to enable it:

```
    bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```

and you need to restart your computer to apply the changes.
You can find the source answer and other possible solutions here: 
https://superuser.com/questions/540055/convenient-way-to-enable-disable-hyper-v-in-windows-8